# Use "true" or "1" for boolean querystring params

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone use "true" or "false" when setting a query string param for a bool?  or do most people use "1" or "0".  I would be curious to know the consensus out there.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I do prefer "1/0", because it doesn't fall under localization requirements.

```
bool isTrue = Request.QueryString["value"] == "1";
```

Comment: Common boolean keywords like “true” or “false” aren’t subject to i18n either.

Comment: You may also find that different languages will change true/false to 1/0 when passed as a parameter and you'll be banging your head trying to figure out why it isn't working.

Answer (score 28):

It may be worth mentioning that when using ASP.NET Core and binding via [[FromQuery]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromqueryattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.2) you are forced to use boolean values as arguments.

```
[HttpGet("/api/foo")]
public Task<NoContentResult> FooAction([FromQuery(Name = "bar")] bool isBar) { /*...*/ }
```

This will work:

```
GET /api/foo?bar=true
```

Passing an integer will result in an invalid `ModelState` returned by ASP.NET Core's ModelBinder

```
GET /api/foo?bar=1
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to use either. A query string parameter does not have to have a value. You could just have a uri like this: `http://someserver.com/somepage.aspx?SortById=&day=Monday`

and then in your code:

```
if(Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("SortById")) ...
```

Comment: hmm, I wonder if anything changes per the framework if that would ever break though.

Comment: What if you submit a form with a checkbox? Regardless of whether it's checked or not, a parameter will still be added to the query string for it.

Answer (score 3):

Most sites use true/false on their query strings, so you won't have to switch from 0/1 back to boolean in your code behind (if statement or something). Number is used more for IDs.

Answer (score 2):

as long as you validate your input it should be less important. both could be parsed into a boolean value.

keep in mind that the querystring parameter could easily changed from somebody else in his browser.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter, to be honest. I've never used a bool in a query string, but I'd probably opt for the '1'.

Comment: +1, I use 1 as well if ever I have to pass a boolean via querystring, but there is a certain programmer here who likes mask his booleans by obfuscation, so the result is "74727565" and "66616C7365" : /

Comment: Besides the the other obvious flaws in that method, I'm sure any would be hacker would notice two fixed values representing true or false :)
Who knows, that programmer might be reading this page.....

Answer (score 1):

"true" or "false" is more readable. 1 or 0 saves character in your URL. I prefer 0 or 1. For converting I use Extension Methods:

```
    public static bool GetBoolVal(this HttpRequest r, string name)
    {
        return r[name] == "1";
    }

    bool yesnot = Page.Request.GetBoolVal("yesno");
```

(pseudo code, not tested)